# android How to get values from thread to mainUI

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm processing some data in the background using `runOnUiThread` but the value for variable (`ishr`) which is being used in processing is getting `null` at the end.

I tried to debug it, every thing works fine and value is present in the `runOnUiThread` block but it is `null` when it comes out of it, is there a way to get the values in mainUI ?

```
public String ishra="";
TextView ish = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ish);
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                processdata.in.background(result);
            }
        });

ish.setText(ishra);


process.data.in.background(String match)
{
    if (match=="True"){
        getdatafromhttp();
        processdata(resultfromhttp);
    }
}

private void processdata(String data)
{ 
    try
    { 
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONObject a = json.getJSONObject("data"); 
        ishra = a.getString("Surprise");
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        Log.wtf("log", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `runOnUiThread` is not background process

Comment: What does `processdata.in.background...` do? Where is that code?

Comment: You appear to have a Context (since you're calling findViewById) so there should be no need to call this as runOnUiThread, you can just invoke `processdata.in.background` directly.

Comment: processdata.in.background() is   parsing JSON data as i was getting error when i put the code directly, after searching  i found this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) where they suggested  many ways to avoid the error  i used this one and there was no error .the problem is the value of ishra is getting null when it comes out of the function runOnUithread

Comment: @Tigger here is the code for the function  processdata.in.backgroundconnect.url.and.get.data(url) ;
          connect.url.and.get.data(url) ;
 private void processdata(String data) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONObject a = json.getJSONObject("data");
             ishra = a.getString("Surprise");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.wtf("log", e);
        }
}  on debugi found the value for ishra to be  some string   but wehn it goes back to mainUI it is getting null

Comment: @Tigger apologies i am new to this  forum. i have added the other imp functions to the script

Comment: Try  AsyncTask its much easier and convenient .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would re-write the code to use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or make the following changes:

```
// ishra is not required any more
//public String ishra="";
TextView ish = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ish);
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            // Set the text here
            ish.setText(processdata.in.background(result));
        }
    });

// Not required any more
//ish.setText(ishra);

// Return a String 
private String process.data.in.background(String match)
{
    private String result = "";
    if (match=="True"){
        // What does getdatafromhttp() do? It may need to be changed.
        getdatafromhttp();
        result = processdata(resultfromhttp);
    }
    return result;
}

private String processdata(String data)
{
    String result = "";
    try
    { 
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONObject a = json.getJSONObject("data"); 
        // Get the result
        result = a.getString("Surprise");
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        Log.wtf("log", e);
    }
    // Return the result String
    return result;
}
```

The reason why your code is not working is because you are calling `ish.setText(ishra);` outside of the `runOnUiThread()` method. This means the `String` assigned to `ishra` within the `runOnUiThread()` is updated after you have called the `setText()` method.

You could shift `ish.setText(ishra);` like so as well:

```
public void run(){
    processdata.in.background(result);
    ish.setText(ishra);
}
```

And if you code is solid, that should work too.

Comment: thanks, yours is a good solution. before trying urs  i was searching for other solution i found  ion[link](https://github.com/koush/ion) by kaushikdutta which is simple solution thanks again for the the reply